# Adding a leading zero to some values in column in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to add leading zero value with some column datatype int/decimal/numeric in sql server. How to achieve that one?

```
update a ---Int/Decimal/Numeric
   set Column='0'+b.column1
from #temp a
,#temp2 b ---Varchar column
where a.id=b.id
```

Expected result: `001234567`
Actual result: `1234567`

Comment: int/decimal/numeric don't consider leading zeors, so it would be discarded

Comment: you have to store as a `varchar` or `char` and need  convert it when to access

Comment: Why would "adding" a character `'0'` as a prefix to an numeric `1234567` result in a value that has _two_ leading zeros as shown in your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

What your query does is add `0` to a numeric datatype: as one would expect, it does not affect it. Basically as commented by @Fahmi, leading zeros are not meaningless for numeric datatypes (and the-like).

You can take care of display matters when fetching the value, typically by converting it to a string, like:

```
select Id, '00' + cast(numberColumn as varchar(9)) from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FORMAT function with a custom format : [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Example : **select format(12, '0000')**

Returns : '**0012**'

PS: Notice that the returned value is a string. Numeric values doesn't have leading zeros, but their string representation can have them.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options.  First, change the type of the column:

```
alter #temp alter column a varchar(255);

update a ---Int/Decimal/Numeric
    set Column = right('000000000' + b.column1, 9)
    from #temp a join
         #temp2 b ---Varchar column
         on a.id = b.id;
```

(Note the use of correct `JOIN` syntax.)

An alternative is a computed column:

```
alter table #temp add column column_formatted as (format(a.column, '000000000'));

-- you still need the update
update a ---Int/Decimal/Numeric
    set Column = try_convert(int, b.column1)
    from #temp a join
         #temp2 b ---Varchar column
         on a.id = b.id;
```